# Animate view with wrap_content in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a view whose height can be increased if user want to edit details in that section and after editing when user will save it then height of that view will be decreased. I need to change height by using animation instead of abrupt change.

I am using this function to animate height

```
fun changeViewSize(view: View, height: Int) {
        val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.measuredHeight, height)
        valueAnimator.duration = 500L
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
            val animatedValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
            val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
            layoutParams.height = animatedValue
            view.layoutParams = layoutParams
            if (animatedValue==0) {view.visibility = View.GONE}
        }
        valueAnimator.start()
    }
```

It works totally fine if I know the height of view, but in my case I have to use `wrap_content` so height will be dynamic.

I have also tried setting `layoutTransition.enableTransitionType` of view so android handle its animation by default but its not clean animation and feels abrupt change.

So how I can animate a view height if its set to wrap content?